# Extracting named groups of regular expression in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

In Python 3, it is quite easy to extract text from named groups as shown in the following example:

```
import re
myStr = r"4000/2000/5000/7000"
reObj = re.compile(r"""(?P<g1>\d+)  # a capturing group named g1
                       /
                       (?P<g2>\d+)
                       /
                       (?P<g3>\d+)
                       /
                       (?P<g4>\d+)""", re.VERBOSE) 
matchObj = reObj.match(myStr)  # match the string to be searched
print(matchObj.group("g1"))  # 4000
print(matchObj.group("g2"))  # 2000 
print(matchObj.group("g3"))  # 5000 
print(matchObj.group("g4"))  # 7000
```

However, in LibreOffice Calc I simply couldn't get any clue (Calc does not even have a independent regex() function which gives a regex pattern). Position-based workarounds as in [this post](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/21562/how-to-extract-element-from-string/) isn't what I need.

PLEASE GIVE ANSWERS INDEPENDENT OF POSITIONAL PARAMETERS and PLEASE EXEMPLIFY EXPLICITLY. e.g. MID() is not acceptable. Although the example given here is simple enough, but I need a general way to deal with a real situation that is far more complex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In both Excel and Calc, the cleanest solution is to create a general-purpose regular expression macro.  To do this in Calc, go to `Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic` and add the following code to Module1:

```vb
Function ReFind(findIn, patt, Optional group_param As Integer,  _
                Optional ignoreCase_param As Boolean)
    ' findIn - string or cell to search in
    ' patt - regexp string or cell containing regexp string
    ' group - which group to grab - analogy to \n in regexp syntax
    ' ignoreCase - false for case sensitive matches
    If IsMissing (group_param) Then
        group = 0
    Else
        group = group_param
    End If
    If IsMissing (ignoreCase_param) Then
        ignoreCase = False
    Else
        ignoreCase = ignoreCase_param
    End If
    oTextSearch = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.util.TextSearch")
    oOptions = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.util.SearchOptions")
    oOptions.algorithmType = com.sun.star.util.SearchAlgorithms.REGEXP
    If ignoreCase Then
        oOptions.transliterateFlags = _
            com.sun.star.i18n.TransliterationModules.IGNORE_CASE
    End If
    oOptions.searchString = patt
    oTextSearch.setOptions(oOptions)
    oFound = oTextSearch.searchForward(findIn, 0, Len(findIn))
    If oFound.subRegExpressions = 0 Then
        ReFind = "No results"
        MsgBox "No results"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf group >= oFound.subRegExpressions Then 
         ReFind = "No result for that group"
         MsgBox "No result for that group"
         Exit Function
    Else
         nStart = oFound.startOffset()
         nEnd = oFound.endOffset()
         ReFind = Mid(findIn, nStart(group) + 1, nEnd(group) - nStart(group))
    End If
End Function
```

Now you can use `ReFind` for any regular expressions needed in the spreadsheet.  For example, in cell A1 enter `12345`.  In cell B1, enter the formula `=REFIND($A$1,"(\d\d)(\d)",2)`.  This will retrieve the third number, which is 3.

The code was adapted from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30502.

Note: It would be better to create the regular expression in python or java using an [add-in](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Spreadsheet_Add-Ins).  However that requires XML declaration files in an extension, which takes more time to set up.

Comment: Works like charm. Deserves 100+ rep. (This answer gives a general solution as well as an directly applicable example.)

Comment: Nice! +1 - now, still deserves 90+ rep ;-)

Comment: This is wonderful, I can even use it in Writer. Now I just need to figure out how to do search and replace with on multiple matches.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK you can't use named groups in LO Calc Search/Replace or formulas, but you can use **numerical references** to pattern groups:

- In the **search** field, you can use `\1` to reference the first pattern group, `\2` for the second and so on.
- In the **replace** expression, use `$1` as reference for the first search pattern group, `$2` for the second and so on.

### Search example

Assuming the four strings `blue bluefish`, `black blackfish`, `blue blackfish` and `black bluefish`, you can replace every string where the same color appears twice (strings 1 and 2) using the search pattern: `(blue|black) \1fish`. The `\1` will reference the matching group, matching the whole string only if the color matched in the regex group `(blue|black)` appears before `fish`, too. ([Example based on the OOo Wiki Documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Grouping_.28....29_and_backreferences_.5Cx_.24x)).

### Replace Example

To transform the string `100/200/300/400` to `300/100/400/200` (with regex enabled in the search options), search for the pattern `(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)` and replace with `$3/$1/$4/$2`.

Comment: Pretty close but may you exemplify (in a directly applicable form)? I tried `=SEARCH(A5, "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)",1)` on cell A5 containing `100/200/300/400` but got `#VALUE`!. I am new to LibreOffice. The section you gave wasn't enough for me to figure out the general logic. Thank you very much.

Comment: The search pattern has to be the first argument, not the second. So, try `=SEARCH("(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)",A5,1)`

Comment: The above gives `1`., not `100`. `=SEARCH("(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)",A5,\1)` or `=SEARCH("(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)",A5,'\1')`  also didn't work. Dollar sign also failed. (LibreOffice 5.0.5.2 @win10 x64)

Comment: Yes, the result is correct. The [`SEARCH()`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#SEARCH) function returns the position of the match. Since you're matching the complete string, beginning at `1`, the result is the start of the string. The third argument is optional, adding an offset to begin the search in the middle of a string. It doesn't set a replacement. SEARCH() just checks for the position but doesn't replace anything.

Comment: So what code should I write, in order to have my cell `B5` give `100`, `C5` give `200`, `D5` give `300` and `E5` give `400`?? May you please EXEMPLIFY EXPLICITLY (and edit in your post)? It is clearly not enough to find the beginning of the match.

Comment: I promise to accept your answer if and only if a solid example which I can verify by simple copy-paste were given. This is the most crucial part missing in the official docs. Sorry again for being this annoying.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but there's no easy solution for this, i fear. There are only a few functions in LO Calc supporting regular expressions, and sadly, neither does REPLACE() nor SUBSTITUTE(). So, the solution depends on your exact needs. If you need a replace function that allows for regex, you may implement it using python or StarBasic with a macro. There are other approaches (e.g., splitting text content by a separator charcters, or even processing data externally). And please remember this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your dedication. I will wait for another 2 days to see if no other reasonable workaround appears, then I will accept this answer.