# Case-sensitive regular expression search formula in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice Calc:

- [`FIND()` is case-sensitive but does not support regular expressions.](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_FIND_function)
- [`SEARCH()` is case-insensitive and supports regular expressions.](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function)

How (in a formula) can I do a case-sensitive search with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this web page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc#Regular_expressions_in_Calc_functions), the `SEARCH()` regular expressions are, by default, case insensitive.  There is an option in the `Tools -> Options -> OpenOffice.org Calc -> Calculate` dialog to change this.

If you are not seeing case insensitive matches with your REs, check that option.

Comment: Thanks. It is checked, the matches are still case-insensitive. Actually on that page it says *"Regular expression searches within functions are always case insensitive, irrespective of the setting of the "Case sensitive" check box on the dialog above"* which is... dumb. I think that might mean it's not possible.

Comment: My bad. I don't have my OpenOffice box available to test, but I re-read the page and I see why you are thinking it is not possible.  I agree it seems unbelievable that this is the case.  Did you check to see if LibreCalc has the same issue?  That project has taken OpenOffice in slightly different directions, but is largely compatible.

Comment: The [LibreOffice docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#SEARCH) say the same: *The search is not case-sensitive.*

Answer (score 1):

For full-featured regular expressions, you'll need a macro.  There is a Basic function here that can be used in a formula:
https://superuser.com/a/1072196/541756

For example, `=REFIND(C10;"BC";;FALSE())` will find "BC" but not "bc".